# Linux computer not booting after permissions change

Tags: boot, bash, terminal, linux-mint

I have been exploring the Linux Mint OS recently.

Can't remember correctly now but I ran a command similar to

```
sudo chmod 700 /./
```

in terminal and am now unable to boot into my computer after turning off.

The computer is stuck on the Linux Mint logo during boot up. I know I brought this problem upon myself. But who knows how I can solve the issue with booting?

*** posting this from phone, sorry if formatting is poor

Comment: What do you see, when you press esc on the Linux Mint logo screen?

Comment: I get an output of processes executed but list is stuck on: "Starting MDM Display Manager        [fail]"

Comment: You'll need to boot a Live CD and correct the permissions from there. On Ubuntu, most of the directories are `0755` and the boot links are `0777`.

Comment: @AFH I am not sure how to change permissions from a live CD. But is it possible to do that through another Linuxmint installation on the same computer?

Comment: Success after changing permissions as @AFH advised! Now able to boot into computer. It looks like 755 works for both boot and root directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot a Live CD or another installation on the same computer to correct the permissions.

You can use its `/` directory as a reference for what the permissions should be - on Ubuntu most are `0755`, except for:

- the symbolic links to the kernel files in the boot directory (`0777`),
- `/lost+found` (`0700`),
- `/tmp` (`1777`) and
- `/net`,`/proc` and `/sys` (`0555`).

On your working system root, you can produce a list of the octal permissions with:

```
stat -c "chmod %a %n" /*
```

Save the output to a file, edit the `/` in the file names to prepend the mount point, and it becomes a script to apply to your repaired system (you will need to either use the `.` or `source` command, or make it executable).

You could even use `sed` to do it all within a single command string, though it is hardly worth the effort, as it's not something I hope you'll ever need to repeat, and it's a good idea to check the commands before executing.

Note the the `/./` in your erroneous command means that only the `/` directory will have been affected.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. My approach was to boot into the second Linuxmint installation which has no permission issues. I then accessed the storage of the main Linuxmint installation with the permission issues. Finally I recursively applied the correct permission settings to the root directory.

Comment: @datum_datem - If this answers your problem, you should mark your question as answered, so others can quickly see that there is a solution.

Comment: I arrived at a solution before this post came. I did not create a list of Octal permissions for use as per your answer. I recursively issued an octal change command to ‘/‘ — which solves my problem but is not an accurate solution. Your answer on the other hand would ensure that permissions are consistent after using a list generated from the live CD/backup installation.

Comment: @datum_datem "Recursive" as in `chmod -R`? If so, you probably messed up permissions further down the directory tree. Different directories need different permissions, and `chmod -R` (with an octal permission) sets them all to be the same for that entire directory (sub)tree.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, I have done “chmod -R” with an octal value. The major issue with doing this would be security related I imagine — is this correct? Do you picture any other issues arising besides security issues?

Comment: @datum_datem Depending on exactly what got changed, there are a large number of things that might go wrong. For example, it might've removed the setuid bit from executables that need to be setuid to do their job. Also, some programs (`sudo` for example) will refuse to operate if they or their config files have insecure (/nonstandard) permissions.

Comment: @Cyrus - I reversed your edit, since the questioner said he called `chmod` on the root directory, so subdirectories would not have changed. It since appears from his comments that he made a recursive call, in which case it is unnecessary to single out the single subdirectory instance `/var/tmp`, since many other files and directories have permissions which differ from `0755`, as @GordonDavisson comments. In either case the change was unnecessary, and could be misleading if the list were taken as exhaustive.

Comment: @datum_datem - You made no mention of a recursive call in your question. If you let it run throughout the entire file system, then you should set everything to `0755` first, _before_ using the script which duplicates the permissions from the live system (which you'll need to use `find` to create). In this way, any files on the damaged system which are absent from the live system will get `0755` permissions, which should be OK for most of them, though you may find occasional permission problems in the future on these files, which you'll need to rectify as they occur.

Comment: @AFH: Good catch.

Comment: @AFH - You are correct, a recursive `chmod R` was not the problem command which was run initially as I state in the question. I only issued `chmod R` in my attempt to correct the permission issues which came up. In anycase, I am able to boot into the main partition/installation now. And have not experienced any issues as yet.

Answer (score 1):

You basically denied permission to everyone except `root` on all files on your system.

Some things during boot do not run as root and cannot perform their tasks.

You can boot into rescue mode and restore permissions, but you have a lot of files and directories to change back.

It's going to be easiest and probably quickest if you just back up your data and reinstall.

Comment: I also feared I had to reinstall but in my case it was possible to boot into a second Linux installation on the same computer and then issue the command to change the permission settings of the root folder.